# Appending a block of code to my.cnf with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to set a bash script to append some lines of code to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld] <-- new code needs to append here
old code
old code
old code
```

Should result into

```
[mysqld]
# set default collation
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
old code
old code
old code
```

I have tried the following, but it does not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Set default collation to UTF-8 in /etc/mysql/my.cnf"

sudo sed -i 'a\
# set default collation\
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci\
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'\
character-set-server = utf8\
,/[mysqld]/d' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: Please why you add backslash at the end of each line in my.cnf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed '/\[mysqld\]/a # set default collation\
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci\
init-connect='\''SET NAMES utf8'\''\
character-set-server = utf8\' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

You can use the append command (`a`), but you need it to operate on the correct line, i.e., the one that matches `/\[mysqld\]/` (this part at the beginning restricts the sed operation to only the matching lines).

The next tricky part is the `'\''`. Basically, if you're inside single quotes, you can't escape the single quote. All you can do is finish the string ('). Then you're in normal bash context so you can pass an escaped single quote (\') and then you start your next single quoted string ('). Since these are not separated by a space, bash will merge them together and pass them to sed as a single argument (the sed command argument).

As for the bash script part, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/etc/mysql/my.cnf"
if [ -w "$file" ] #Check if you have write permissions
then
  echo "Setting default collation to UTF-8 in /etc/mysql/my.cnf" 
  sed '/\[mysqld\]/a # set default collation\
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci\
init-connect='\''SET NAMES utf8'\''\
character-set-server = utf8\' -i "$file"

else
  echo "Can't write to $file. ry running the script with 'sudo'."
fi
```

Comment: This works, but to a point. I get the whole file, with correct edits/appends outputted in buffer, but if i then check the file, there are no changes at all. Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry, my version is without the `sudo` and without the `-i` (in place switch). You need to add those. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I do run it with sudo, forgot to mention.

Comment: It add "\" a backslash at the end of each line

Comment: I join Umesh and want to ask a newb question please. Why it adds a backslash at the end of each line? What is the aim?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers OP had the backslashes in there. I just copied them. It doesn't work without the backslashes, but they get printed if they're used. I don't know ho to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/\[mysqld\]/[mysqld]\
# set default collation\
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci\
init-connect='\''SET NAMES utf8'\''\
character-set-server = utf8/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: @Rastur Oh, I missed that you have quotes in the replacement. Updated the answer..

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution, all in one place:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="/etc/mysql/my.cnf"
if [ -w "$file" ] #Check if you have write permissions
then
  echo "Setting default collation to UTF-8 in /etc/mysql/my.cnf"
  sed '/\[mysqld\]/a # set default collation\
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci\
init-connect='\''SET NAMES utf8'\''\
character-set-server = utf8\' -i $file

else
  echo "Can't write to $file. Try running the script with 'sudo'."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
awk '/\[mysqld\]/ {$0=$0"\nnew data\nadd here"}1' file
```

With your data:

```
awk '/\[mysqld\]/ {$0=$0"\n# set default collation\ncollation-server = utf8_unicode_ci\ninit-connect="q"SET NAMES utf8"q"\ncharacter-set-server = utf8"}1' q="'" file
[mysqld]
# set default collation
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
old code
old code
old code
```

Since single quote within `awk` code is some complicated, you can just add it outside in a variable, then use it in your code.

Comment: I get the same as with the sed solution. A correctly edited file is outputted in buffer, but the file itself remains unchanged.

Comment: @Rastur To change the file using `awk` do: `awk 'code' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.  For `sed` it more simple, just add `-i` like this: `sed -i 'code'`